# Putting text on top of images

Tags: html, css

I have images that are acting in place of radio button inputs. I am trying to write text directly on top of these images, but I can't find an easy way to achieve this.

I will also need to write on top of images that serve as links, so ideally a way which will work in both instances would be best.

```css
#selector {
  width: 5vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + image {
border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">100</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">250</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="500" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">500</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1000" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">1000</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1500" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">1500</label>
```

Comment: Try using z-index or absolute positioning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using `background-image`?

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  outline: 2px solid green;
}
label {
  background-image: url('http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png');
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="rb1" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
<label for="rb1">100</label>
<input id="rb2" type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
<label for="rb2">250</label>
<input id="rb3" type="radio" name="amount" value="500" />
<label for="rb3">500</label>
<input id="rb4" type="radio" name="amount" value="1000" />
<label for="rb4">1000</label>
<input id="rb5" type="radio" name="amount" value="1500" />
<label for="rb5">1500</label>
```

Comment: nice. I did try with a background, but I think I tried to fix this to the input rather than the label! Can't seem to size the image now though? - I like to use vw;

Comment: [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)

Comment: Doesn't work? it stays the same size as the space the label text fills. I can make the font size larger of course, but the background images are all still different sizes?

Comment: @J.Ayo Remove the `min-width` and `min-height` styles from the label. Then you can set the `width` and `height` to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, set the label to `display:inline-block;`and the `<span>`(where goes the text) to `display:block;` and give a `bottom` negative position:

**CSS**

```
    #selector {
      width: 5vw;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }

    input[type="radio"]:checked + image {
      border: 2px solid green;
    }

    label {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    label span {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      bottom: -20px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <span>teste</span>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">100</label>
<label>
  <span>teste</span>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">250</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="500" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">500</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1000" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">1000</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1500" />
  <img id="selector" src="http://s8.postimg.org/k4wy7buc1/selector.png">1500</label>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/eq1swfd2/2/)**

Comment: I meant over the top of the image

Comment: Simple, just add more two rules to label span{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
} I edit my answer

Comment: hmm almost, but now if resize window, the text moves above or below, can it not be fixed over the images?